# Hide all windows not working

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, autohide

When I hide all windows using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Super+D it hides some but not all of the windows. The remaining windows cannot be clicked and are visible behind the desktop.

System: Ubuntu 20.04, with tweaks: dash-to-panel, and I changed to nemo as the default file and desktop manager. I suspect this last change is responsible but I haven't used Ubuntu 20.04 long enough before I made this change to be sure the issue was not already present.

Is there any way to fix it.

This is what my desktop looks like AFTER hiding all windows:

[image: After hiding all windows]

The applications that are still visible cannot be clicked before they are brought in front of the desktop through other means.

---

I still encounter this from time to time. I am not reliably able to reproduce it but I have the suspicion it is caused by interacting with desktop icons after hiding all windows.

Comment: Try with the [Alt-F4 + R] key combination to restart Gnome, if the problem keeps going tell me.

Comment: @MartinPrado, I assume you are not trolling me to close my window (Alt+F4). Should this do something when not in any application and do you mean Alt+F4+R? I can reboot and see whether the issue persists. Perhaps better anyway.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I meant Alt-F2, that way you woldn't have to reboot everything, just the Gnome shell

Comment: Okay upon a reboot it was fixed, but then I managed to reproduce it. I rebooted again (hadn't read your reply yet) to test under which circumstances it happens but now I can't reproduce it anymore. I will update the question next time it happens if I get a better idea of what might be causing it.